# provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server, pgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-web-api2, dapper

I am using Dapper to connect to pgsql database. The below code was working few days back. But don't know why its not working now. The same credentials are working with pgadmin3 but not with the c# code. 
here is the controller method, for simplicity I wrote all db code in Get method.

the below code was

```
public IEnumerable<Item> Get()
    {
        string connString = "Server=192.168.1.11;Database=db_alpha1;Uid=postgres;Pwd=xxxxxx";

        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            db.Open();

            return db.Query<Item>("Select * From items").ToList();
        }
    }
```

Here is the error on line  `db.Open();`:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Also, I already configured pg_hba.conf file, added my system ip address.

Comment: SqlConnection is a class used to connect to Sql Server. You should use the appropriate classes from the Npgsql ADO.NET provider

Comment: I am using Dapper library for db connectivity and I thing this is correct way to connect, even it was working few days back.

Comment: No that cannot work SqlConnection is for Sql Server, to use Postgres you should work with [this](http://www.npgsql.org/). Dapper has nothing to do with the code that connects to the database. This is done through stock NET classes (SqlConnection, OleDbConnection) or through specific ADO.NET providers (MySqlConnection, OracleConnection and [NpgsqlConnection](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/))

Comment: oh thanks Steve, it was my mistake, I used ngpsql in another project, now its working. replced, NpgsqlConnection with SqlConnection .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Steve. The issue has resolved, it was a silly mistake, I replaced 
SqlConnection with NpgsqlConnection, and added npgsql package.